# DateTimeField input format failing to parse str

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-datetime

I have the following field:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    startDate = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'])

activity = {u'startDate': "2015-10-18 15:11:50 +0000"}
serializer = ActivitySerializer(data=activity)
serializer.is_valid() # False
serializer.errors
# {'startDate': [u'Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss [+HHMM|-HHMM].']}
```

Any thoughts as to why the datetime string that I'm using doesn't match that format? Given that datetime string, what's the right format string to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new field, `ActivityStartDateField`, and implemented a custom `to_internal_value`. I'm surprised I couldn't get it to work with the built-in `DateTimeField`.

```
class ActivityStartDateField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return str(obj)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        dt = arrow.get(data,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').datetime
        return dt
```